# "Primitive types" versus "built-in value types"

Tags: c#, types

I recently caught an exception in C# while using the Array.SetValue(Int32) method. The exception was:

> Cannot widen from source type to target type either because the source
>   type is a not a primitive type or the conversion cannot be
>   accomplished.

The reference to the word "primitive" surprised me a bit because I thought the tendency was to refer to these types as built-in types, also that the term "primitive type" was an informal term. What is the difference between "primitive" types and "built-in value types"? I don't find a definition of primitive types in the C# language specification.

Comment: Primitive types are defined in the CLR, not C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900.aspx

Comment: Example: DateTime is a value type but it is not a primitive. `int`, `char` etc are primitives.

Comment: You can make that an Answer

Comment: @RudiVisser - The link you posted contains the line `Visual Basic .NET defines the following primitive types:`

Comment: @MartinSmith Indeed, I've linked a better resource in my answer version.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Primitive Types are not defined in the C# Language Specification. They are instead defined in .NET itself, and the best reference for primitive types is to look straight at [`Type.IsPrimitive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) on MSDN. Specifically, the Remarks section lists the primitive types that are available.

So that we've got a complete reference here, these are the primitive types defined in the [CLI Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf) (Section I.8.2.2):

- [`Boolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx)
- [`Byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx)
- [`SByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.sbyte.aspx)
- [`Int16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.aspx)
- [`UInt16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16.aspx)
- [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)
- [`UInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.aspx)
- [`Int64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx)
- [`UInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.aspx)
- [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx)
- [`UIntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uintptr.aspx)
- [`Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx)
- [`Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx)
- [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx)

Contrary to popular belief, just because a type has a corresponding keyword does **not** make it a primitive type, the best example is probably `string`.

Value types, on the other hand, may or may not be primitives also. There are lots of value types "built-in" to the .NET Framework in addition to those defined in the CLI Spec, but they are not classed as primitives. A good example is [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), which is a `struct` provided by the .NET Framework, by that definition it could be considered a "built-in value type". You can read more about value types (which will of course cover the built-in ones also) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).