# Is there a test to see if unknown object is of a value type?

Tags: c#

The definition of [Value Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx) I'm working with.

If I get an object member

```
class SampleClass{

    object SampleMember{ get; set; }
}
```

And set it in one function...

```
public SampleClass foo(SampleClass bar){

      bar.SampleMember = 6m;
      return bar;
}
```

And need to test it in another; the test needs to know if it's a reference type, or a value type (in this case; decimal).

```
public SampleClass blick(SampleClass spok){

    if( TestUtilities.IsAValueType(bar.SampleMember) )
    {
        DoBlickWorkOnSpok(spok)
    }
    return spok;
}
```

What sort of test can be done on spok to test if it's a value type?

Comment: @Servy Primitive Types aka Predefined types or built-in types, check this out : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @chomba Given the context, I don't think the OP is actually referring to built in types, but if he is, he should use that term, because if he did, then the question would be answerable as that is a well defined term.  What you linked to is in the *VB.NET* specs, and is specific to that language.  The types in that list will also differ from the built in types in C#, which is why using proper terminology is important; it changes the meaning.

Comment: @Servy FWIW the language specification refers to `int` and `double` as primitive types in the introduction, but you're right that it isn't a formal definition.

Comment: Just as a FYI, apparently built-in types and primitive types are not the same have a look at this answer: [“Primitive types” versus “built-in value types”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16589255/3052062)

Comment: Fair enough - I'll update the question to make it more clear. I was asking the wrong question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primitive types can be determined 
as:

`var p = 0;
 bool result = p.GetType().IsPrimitive`

value types can be determined

as:

```
     var a = 0;
     bool x = a is System.ValueType;
```

//x = true in this case

also it is the compiler which defines its primitive types.

CLR only understands the types as either Value types or Reference types.

Comment: Why do you equate "primitive type" with value types? Would you consider some `struct ExtremelyComplicatedMess { /* 1000 properties go here */ }` a "primitive type"? Would the OP? Fact is, the OP hasn't stated (as of now) what he considers a primitive type (except that `decimal` is one of them), so this is really not much more than a guess in the dark.

Comment: @stakx Well, in the case of the question, he wants to know if it's "a primitive or a reference type", meaning one or the other; that only makes sense if by "primitive" he meant "value type".  But that's still a pretty shaky argument.  Fundamentally the question is unclear, and unfortunately people are choosing to throw darts at the dart board blindly rather than closing the unclear question as unclear.

Comment: @Servy: _"unfortunately people are choosing to throw darts at the dart board blindly rather than closing the unclear question as unclear"_. Well said. That's exactly what I intended to hint at with my above comment.

Comment: @stakx got your point about answering an incomplete question, and anyways my answers for *primitive type is incorrect. Will correct it

Comment: Even though the question wasn't clear I gave this the answer because he covered all the bases anyway and instead of squabbling over various possible meaning gave possible other avenues of reasonable answers to my poorly worded OP.

Answer (score 1):

try:

`bar.SampleMember.GetType().IsPrimitive`

In your example you specifically mention "decimal" Microsoft doesn't define decimal as a primitive. If you also check whether it is specifically a decimal, in addition to `IsPrimitive` that may get you what you need:

```
bar.SampleMember.GetType().IsPrimitive || bar.SampleMember is decimal
```

Comment: Your definition of primitive seems to conflict with the OP's definition.  (Which is unsurprising, given that there are many different definitions of the term in general, and C# doesn't define one for the language.)

Comment: @Servy Microsoft defines it as: "The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single." according to IsPrimitive. However, the OP does mention decimal. Decimal is not included in that list. I will update my answer

Comment: @dman2306 That's the CLR's definition of "is a primitive".  The OP doesn't seem to be looking for that, given his question.

Comment: @Servy I will revise my answer if the OP clarifies. At this point though, I think this is going to be very close (if not exactly) what the OP wants based on my reading of the question.

Comment: @dman2306 You have no idea what he wants, because there are at least half a dozen different readings of the question.  Being fairly close but subtly off is very likely to be *worse* than not having an answer at all.  Having an incorrect answer that looks like it is correct is *actively harmful*.  Blindly guessing among many different options not only a waste of time, but is actively harmful.  The OP needs to clarify what he is actually asking for.  Just picking some random option out of a hat to answer isn't helping.

Comment: @Servy. I disagree. Given that the OP did not define "primitive" I believe using the definition provided by the CLR is appropriate. Words have meanings. If someone does not provide a specific definition they wish to use, then it is correct to use the standard definition. Just because you do not believe Microsoft's definition of primitive does not make their definition wrong. Calling this answer "actively harmful" seems inappropriate as well as StackOverflow is not just a Q&A forum, it is a learning and discussion forum. I bet there are people who read this and didn't know IsPrimitive existed.

Comment: Given that the OP didn't define primitive, and it can mean lots of different things in lots of different situations *we don't know what he means*.  You're taking the word that he used and *using it in an entirely different context*.  He could have meant the CLR's definition of a primitive, he could have meant VB's definition of a primitive, he could have meant a built in type, he could have meant a value type, he could have had his own definition separate from all of the others, etc.  And of course, as per the edit to the question, it turns out you *didn't* guess correctly in your blind guess.

Comment: I never said that MS's definition of the term is wrong.  MS itself has several definitions, and *none of them apply to the context of the question*.  MS has given certain words certain meanings *in particular contexts*.  Outside of those contexts, they don't apply.  Saying that your incorrect answer to a question is helpful because someone didn't know about some of the information in your incorrect answer is also a false argument.  If you want to inform people about the existence of `IsPrimitive` then do so in response to a question where that information is actually the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any *definition* of primitive types in C#. All types inherit the `System.Object` and they are split into two categories, the `reference` types and the `value` types.  The

[image]

The above picture is taken from C#  Language Specification version 5.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that there's "no concept" of primitive types - the [.NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) itself identifies certain types as primitive - but there's not a single definition for "primitive" types specific to C# (`string` and `decimal` are not primitive types as defined by the framework).

Comment: @DStanley There is no *unified* or *clear* concept of a primitive type in that context.  There are lots of subtly or even radically different things that people mean when they use the term.  For the purposes of answering a question about it, "tons of wildly inconsistent concepts" is pretty darn close to "no concept".

Comment: @DStanley I agree with you. This was actually my intention saying that there isn't any concept of primitive types in `C#`. I didn't mention the .NET framework, because in this case there are certain primitive types. Furthermore, for the first time I tried to search in the C# language specification the term primitive and I didn't find anything. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Servy I agree, but I would still argue that "no definition" is much closer to the truth than "no concept".

Comment: @DStanley I changed the term "concept" to "definition", hoping to not causing any problem.