# What is special about .NET primitive types?

Tags: .net, primitive-types, ecma

I was reading about primitive types on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900(v=vs.71).aspx), but then I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589255/347172) on a StackOverflow question about primitive types. The two seem to differ ever so slightly.

According to the msdn documentation, it states a few of the advantages of primitive types:

- Primitive types permit literal values.
- Primitive types can be declared as constant values.
- Operands of an expression made up of all primitive types can be compiled into a constant expression.

---

However, the part that differs is that the StackOverflow states that `System.String`, for example, is not a primitive type. This makes sense: `typeof(System.String).IsPrimitive` yields `false`. And, the StackOverflow answer points to the CLI Spec: ECMA 335 (link is broken) as its source of reference. This leads me to believe that the msdn documentation is not entirely accurate. If that is the case, then what makes primitive types so special?

Comment: The MSDN link is ancient, about a version of Visual Studio that is no longer supported. Besides, the link is about Visual Basic, not the CLI

Comment: The question still boils down to, what is special about primitive types?

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN link points to an ancient page about Visual Basic.NET 2003. In the [current specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234437.aspx) String was removed from the list of primitive types. The [Visual Basic Language *Reference*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) doesn't mention String as a primitive type, even for VB.NET 2003.

I suspect this was a documentation error back in 2003

Comment: Fair enough, so what makes primitive types special?